R script for Bernoulli Equation from reservoir to pipe outlet with friction loss
I was able to write a script that used height as a function for resulting flow out of a pipe. Script attached. However, I am having issues adapting the script to account for friction loss within the pipe.
library(ggplot2) #load ggplot for graphing

#Bernouli Principle
#Velocity @ outflow: V = sqrt(2gh)
#flowrate: Q = sqrt(2gh)*cs_area
#Hazen-Williams
#Pipe friction loss: H_loss = 10.4643*L*((Q/C)^1.852)/(D^4.857)

calculate_flow_rate <- function(height, gravity, cs_area){
  
  #constants & input parameters
  gravity <- 32.2 #ft/s^2
  diameter <- 4 #ft
  cs_area <- 12.57 #ft^2
  density <- 1.94 #slugs/ft^3
  C_coeff <- 120
  flow_rate <- (sqrt(2 * gravity * height) * cs_area)
  
  return(flow_rate)
}

height <- seq(0, 59, by = 1) # heights from 0 to 59 by 1 ft increments
flow_rates <- sapply(height, function(h) calculate_flow_rate(h, gravity, cs_area))

data <- data.frame(Height = height, Flow_Rate = flow_rates)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Height, y = Flow_Rate)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Height (ft)", y = "Flow Rate (cfs)")

Script with friction loss below
library(ggplot2) #load ggplot for graphing

#Bernouli Principle
#Velocity @ outflow: V = sqrt(2gh)
#flowrate: Q = sqrt(2gh)*cs_area
#Hazen-Williams
#Pipe friction loss: H_loss = 10.4643*L*((Q/C)^1.852)/(D^4.857)

calculate_flow_rate <- function(height, gravity, cs_area){
  
  #constants & input parameters
  gravity <- 32.2 #ft/s^2
  cs_area <- 12.57 #ft^2
  flow_rate <- (sqrt(2 * gravity * height) * cs_area)
  
  return(flow_rate)
}

calculate_headloss <-function(flow_rate, C_coeff, p_length, diameter){
  
  diameter <- 4 #ft
  C_coeff <- 120
  p_length <- 320 #ft
  headloss <- 10.4543*p_length*((flow_rate/C_coeff)^1.852)/(diameter^4.857)
  
  return(headloss)
}
  
calculate_new.flowrate <-function(height, gravity, headloss, density){
  
  fdensity <- 1.94 #slugs/ft^3
  new.flowrate <- sqrt((2*gravity*height)-(2*headloss/fdensity))
  
  return(new.flowrate)
}


### Graphing Code###

height <- seq(0, 59, by = 1) # heights from 0 to 59 by 1 ft increments
flow_rates <- sapply(height, function(h) calculate_new.flowrate(h, flow_rate, headloss))
data <- data.frame(Height = height, Flow_Rate = flow_rates)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Height, y = Flow_Rate)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Height (ft)", y = "Flow Rate (cfs)")

I get various errors, depending on how I change the "calculate_new.flowrate(h, ...) variables.
Thanks in advance.

flow_rate is not defined when calling: flow_rates <- sapply(height, function(h) calculate_new.flowrate(h, flow_rate, headloss))
